# create second samba4 active directory domain controller for backup

Tags: ubuntu, domain, directory, samba4, controller

I built up a samba4 active directory domain controller on ubuntu 14.04 and everything is working fine. The Windows clients can log in and do stuff. So far so good.

However, in case of emergency, I want to have a second samba4 ad dc, which will take the place of the first one. Both should be "identically" concerning functionallity and data up-to-dateness.

Is it possible to run two samba4 ad dc servers parallel, which are communicating with each other, and if one goes down, the other one is replacing the "main" server ? If so, how to achieve this goal? Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Active directory knows the concept of multiple DCs replicating in a multi-master fashion. That means that you can add additional DCs to your existing domain. See the [full instructions on the Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Join_a_domain_as_a_DC).

In this setup, all DCs for the domain will be active simultaneously, and clients will use all of them. If one DC fails, the clients will simply continue to use the other DC(s). If a DC should be taken out of the domain, the process is called demotion of the DC. There are also [notes for that](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Demote_a_Samba_DC) on the Samba Wiki.

Note that the replication that is currently impemented with Samba only treats the directory data, not file share data. While there are file replication mechanisms in Windows, these are not fully implemented in Samba yet. If you want to do serious file sharing, you may want to do that not on the DCs but on additional Samba servers that are members of the domain. You would then make the file server highly available by establishing a backup of the data to a different server that is configured to take over the file server role if the productive file server fails. (Alternatively, a clustered/distributed file system could be used to store the file server data and samba could be clustered with [CTDB](https://ctdb.samba.org/), but that might be an overkill for your purposes.)

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your first DC with Samba4, the term used is that you "provision" the domain.  Among other things, provisioning creates the databases Samba uses.

Then when you add another DC (and you should have at least 2) you install Samba on it, configure it to use the first DC as its nameserver, and then join the domain.  This will replicate the databases to the new DC and allow it to validate logins, etc.   As mentioned in the other answer, the Samba wiki has [instructions for joining another DC.](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Join_a_domain_as_a_DC)

When you add another DC, be sure to follow the step labelled "GID mappings of built-in groups."  One of the tricky things with Samba4 is getting all the mapping of UIDs/GIDs to work properly and with DCs you *really* want to do that step.

Unlike Windows Servers, Samba doesn't replicated the contents of the sysvol folder among DCs.  If you want to use GPOs (which are stored under sysvol), you'll have to set up something to sync them yourself.

Finally a warning: demoting your first DC - which will hold the 5 (or 7, depending on how you count) FSMO roles - is problematic.